# Windows 7+Ubuntu 12.04 dual boot partitioning confusion

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, multi-boot, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to dual boot desktop Ubuntu for the first time, and hopelessly flummoxed by the partitioning process.  I've got a Lenovo notebook (Windows 7) with a 500GB HDD + 28GB SSD, and my goal is to create a single small (~24GB) Ubuntu partition on the HDD for both the OS and filesystem (i.e. I don't need to share files between Ubuntu and Windows).

This is what I see in Windows Disk Management, after shrinking the C: partition to leave that 23.44 GB of unallocated space:

[image: 1]

There are only 3 primary partitions (SYSTEM_DRV, C:, and D:), so there should be room for another.  I assume the OEM partition is a system restore partition.

I'm totally lost about what to do on the Ubuntu side.  When I try to install it from a bootable USB stick, I don't see any devices in the list:

[image: 2]

I've tried 12.10,12.04,32-bit,64-bit, and multiple USB sticks, but nothing ever shows up, and the buttons along the bottom are inactive.  I'm supposed to choose a device from that field, right?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have little experience with SSD setups, so I'm going to give this my best shot.

First, have you tried running a check on the installation image to make sure that it's not "dirty"?

Try deleting any partitions that you plan on using for the Ubuntu install and leaving them as free space. Remember that you can always make partitions to the right, but never to the left.